# ValueError: continuous is not supported with xgboost classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

This is my error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7c13d55b8367> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
      2 y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
----> 3 cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
      4 print(cm)
      5 accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

**2nd Frame**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     95     # No metrics support "multiclass-multioutput" format
     96     if (y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]):
---> 97         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
     98 
     99     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('NBA_proj_14.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -13].values
```

Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Training XGBoost on the Training set

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
classifier = XGBClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Making the Confusion Matrix

````
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)```
````

Here is my dataset

[image]

Comment: Okay, and what is your *question* about this error message? Did you *read* the error message? Did you *understand* the error message? For example, can you understand what `y_type` refers to in that context, and why it is trying to use `"continuous"`? Does it make sense to you that a continuous type is not supported? Did you *expect* the input to have those characteristics?  If so, why are you trying to create this confusion matrix, and what is your understanding of how that should work? If not, what happened when you tried to diagnose why it does?

Comment: Please do not block quote your text, and try to give *descriptive* titles to your posts (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -13].values
```

Instead of building a features array `X` and a target array `y`, you are splitting your dataset row-wise, which is not what you want.

You alone know what/where the class you want to predict is, which you want to make your target array. As hinted by the error, when doing classification, building a confusion matrix, you should not be predicting a continuous variable.

Comment: so given my code example, how would I split the input features & output features since the output is continuous ?